# Bind list item onpress in FLATLIST ( React Native )

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Creating a list of items in my project using flatlist. My items rendering fine in the list.

There is 1 favorite icon there to select the product as favorite. 
From my data i am changing the icon on the base either this product is favorite or not.

what i want is to bind each product to mark as favorite and change the color. 
in short needs to toggle favorite and not favorite icon.

> My code
>
> Data i am rendering

```
 entries: [
            { id: 1, is_fav: false, title: 'hello', ImagePath: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/03/01/00/55/flowers-19830_960_720.jpg' },
            { id: 2, is_fav: true, title: 'world', ImagePath: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/07/01/19/48/background-2462434_960_720.jpg' },
            { id: 3, is_fav: false, title: 'you', ImagePath: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/16/15/25/christmas-1911637_960_720.jpg' },
            { id: 4, is_fav: true, title: 'you', ImagePath: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/10/17/27/sparkler-839831_960_720.jpg' },
            { id: 5, is_fav: false, title: 'hello', ImagePath: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/03/01/00/55/flowers-19830_960_720.jpg' }]
```

> Flatlist

```
<FlatList
                    data={this.state.entries}
                    numColumns={this.state.columns}
                    key={this.state.key}
                    renderItem={this.Render_flatlist_Data}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                    ListHeaderComponent={this.Render_FlatList_Sticky_header}
                    stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}

                />

    Render_flatlist_Data = ({ item: rowData }) => {
.....
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.TickFav()}>
   <Text>
    <Icon name={(rowData.is_fav === true ? 'heart' : 'ios-heart-empty')} 
   size={25} color="#ddd" /> </Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
.....
}
```

How i can make the product fav when click on the product favorite icon.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all we need to have a **variable to watch** [extraData] that the state data has been changed. (i.e) some product has been marked or un-marked as favourite.

This helps the flatlist to notify that a value has been changed, so that we have to re-render.

In Your case, adding **extraData**  field in Flatlist should do fine

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.entries}

  extraData={this.state}

  numColumns={this.state.columns}
  key={this.state.key}
  renderItem={this.Render_flatlist_Data}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
  ListHeaderComponent={this.Render_FlatList_Sticky_header}
  stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
/>

TickFav = rowData => {
  rowData.is_fav = !rowData.is_fav
  this.setState({});
}
```

You can even get **the actual rowData** from the state and **change it directly**, which is not needed.

```
TickFav = (index) => {
  const {entries} = this.state;
  entries[index].is_fav = !entries[index].is_fav;
  this.setState({entries});
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mukundhan for your quick reply. your solution worked for me. Thanks again.

Comment: My pleasure. :)

Answer (score 0):

pass `rowData` as parameter in `onPress` method and update `is_fav` status when click on item.

```
TickFav = (rowData) => {
    rowData.is_fav = !rowData.is_fav
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onPress for your items, when you will click on your item pass the id and on the base of that id check for the item and toggle its fav accordingly.

```
onPress={() => {his.TickFav(id) }
```